# How to uninstall chruby?

Tags: ruby, chruby

OS X 10.9.4. I did not install the `chruby` by homebrew.

I would love to uninstall the [chruby](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby). Because I want to do a fresh install again.

I think I need to go to where chruby it is. And [run `make uninstall`](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby#uninstall)

I tried to find where it is:

```
➜  ~  whereis chruby
➜  ~  which chruby
chruby () {
  case "$1" in
    (-h|--help) echo "usage: chruby [RUBY|VERSION|system] [RUBY_OPTS]" ;;
    (-V|--version) echo "chruby: $CHRUBY_VERSION" ;;
    ("") local dir star
      for dir in "${RUBIES[@]}"
      do
        dir="${dir%%/}"
        if [[ "$dir" = "$RUBY_ROOT" ]]
        then
          star="*"
        else
          star=" "
        fi
        echo " $star ${dir##*/}"
      done ;;
    (system) chruby_reset ;;
    (*) local dir match
      for dir in "${RUBIES[@]}"
      do
        dir="${dir%%/}"
        [[ "${dir##*/}" = *"$1"* ]] && match="$dir"
      done
      if [[ -z "$match" ]]
      then
        echo "chruby: unknown Ruby: $1" >&2
        return 1
      fi
      shift
      chruby_use "$match" "$*" ;;
  esac
}
```

But could not find it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just do

```
wget -O chruby-0.3.8.tar.gz https://github.com/postmodern/chruby/archive/v0.3.8.tar.gz
tar -xzvf chruby-0.3.8.tar.gz
cd chruby-0.3.8/
```

and

```
sudo make uninstall
```

Comment: make sure to download the same version as the one installed (it didn't work for me otherwise)